# How can I copy from a template node and fill with json data and append them to the document with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, templates

In some case, I need to copy from a node template and fill some fields of the node with json data. How can I do that? For example in HTML file I have written such a template:

```
<div id="template" style="display:none">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <p>{{content}}</p>
</div>
```

and my json data is

```
[{"name":"A","content":"B"},{"name":"C","content":"D"},{"name":"E","content":"F"}]
```

and I want to generate three nodes and append them to the document.

Also, the

node maybe binded with some click **event** and I want the new node actions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be best off using a templating library - my favourite is [jQuery.tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) but there are others.

You'd have to modify your template like so:

```
<script id='template' type='text/x-jquery-tmpl'>
  <h1>${name}</h1>
  <p>${content}</p>
</script>
```

then render it like this:

```
$('#template').tmpl(data).appendTo('body');
```

where `data` is your array. This will create a separate template instance for each member of the array.

For a quick guide to jQuery.tmpl have a look at [my slides](http://skilldrick.co.uk/tmpl/) or [my presentation](http://bristolrb.org/2011/02/04/first-video-online.html).

If you want to bind events, either bind them after you've added the rendered template to the DOM, or use `live` or `delegate`.